# Scope a Post with his association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how we can scope a Post with his association table ?
I explain what I want to do it will be more clear. I actually have a scaffold :ranch, and a scaffold :staff. And when I create a new Staff, I can choose to associated it with many ranches. So I have an other table to reference this association :ranch_staff.

So if I want to scope the staff to display only which are associated with the actual @ranch, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

migration:

```
class Init < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ranches do |t|
      t.string "name"
    end

    create_table :staffs do |t|
      t.string "name"
    end

    create_table :ranches_staffs, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :ranch
      t.belongs_to :staff
    end
  end
end
```

`app/models/staff.rb`:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ranches
end
```

`app/models/ranch.rb`:

```
class Ranch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staffs
end
```

run in rails console:

```
staff1 = Staff.create(name: "staff1")
staff2 = Staff.create(name: "staff2")
staff3 = Staff.create(name: "staff3")
staff4 = Staff.create(name: "staff4")
ranch1 = Ranch.create(name: "ranch1")
ranch2 = Ranch.create(name: "ranch1")
staff1.ranches << ranch1
staff2.ranches << ranch1
staff3.ranches << ranch2
staff4.ranches << ranch2
```

Now you can access `ranch1`'s staff by

```
ranch1.staffs
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Staff id: 1, name: "staff1">, #<Staff id: 2, name: "staff2">]>
```

See [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).